# PowerShell run .ps1 with parameters remotely

Tags: powershell

How do I run a `.ps1` script with parameters remotely? Currently I have come across

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -FilePath "./testdelete.ps1 -location $Folder"
```

I have tried `$using:Folder` it does not work. It does not seem to pass the folder info to the script.

Answer (score 1):

The  [Invoke-Command](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135225) cmdlet has a `-ArgumentList` parameter:

> Enter the values in a comma-separated list. Values are associated with
>   variables in the order that they are listed.

**Example:**

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -FilePath "./testdelete.ps1" -ArgumentList $Folder
```